# Chamar código php em botão

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Gostaria de saber como faço para chamar um código php em um botão que aciona um iframe, sendo que esse código deveria ser aberto no iframe.

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes? Já tem o HTML do botão e do iframe? Tem alguma tentativa já feita?

Comment: Sim já tenho, eu fiz uma função com um document.getElementById  cm o código php coloquei um button com a função que eu criei e no parentese da getelement eu coloquei o id do iframe, mas não funciona

Comment: Então, você poderia editar a pergunta com o código que você já tentou? A versão mais resumida possível dele, somente para reproduzir o problema.

Answer (score 2):

Para chamar um código PHP após clicar nesse botão, use uma requisição AJAX para o arquivo PHP desejado.

Se o código deve ser executado no iframe, então use o `src` para o arquivo PHP ou integre ele à página que precisa. Caso seja necessário passar alguma variável pela URL, basta que o faça pelo `src` e capture as informações pelo `$_GET` no PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ativar o iframe e setar o src dele dinamicamente como nesse jsfiddle que eu acabei de fazer:
http://jsfiddle.net/Te7ps/

Answer (score -1):

Bem, sem muita delongas:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['act'])) {
  echo "Olá, Stack Overflow!"; //Seu código vai aqui, enfim...
} else {
?>
(.. html ..)
<form action="index.php" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
  <input type="submit" value="Clique aqui!">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Você chegou a ler e interpretar a pergunta dela?

Comment: Sim, agora é só ela adaptar ao que ela quer e necessita, aqui não é lugar de códigos prontos.

Comment: Não creio que seu código esteja adaptável para a necessidade dela... Você apenas fez um formulário que chama uma requisição get.

Comment: Mas não está chamando o código em PHP?

Comment: O interesse principal dela é usar o iframe, algo que não foi citado em sua resposta. rs

Comment: Se ela não souber implementar o iframe ali... é complicado. Corrija a resposta e eu edito.